# Omit empty dictionary and parent properties when serializing with Json.Net

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following code:

```
var data = new {
    name = "Jon Doe",
    properties = new
    {
        homes = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    },
    age = 34
}

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
    ContractResolver = new MyResolver()
};

var serializationResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, settings)
```

The Json.Net contract resolver `MyResolver` is defined as follow:

```
class MyResolver : DefaultContractResolver {
protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (property.PropertyType.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType &&
            typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))
        {
            property.ShouldSerialize =
                instance =>
                {
                    var value = instance.GetType().GetProperty(property.PropertyName).GetValue(instance, null);
                    return (value as IDictionary).Count > 0;
                };
        }

        return property;
        }
}
```

My problem is that the json result of the serialization is the following:

```
{
  "name": "Jon Doe",
  "properties": {},
  "age": 34
}
```

but I would like to get rid of the property `"properties": {}`, which means that I would like to obtain the json

```
{
  "name": "Jon Doe",
  "age": 34
}
```

I have done unsuccessful attempts to get rid of these kind of properties that result to be empty after removing their childs, how could I accomplish this?

Comment: You are omitting the empty dictionary here (the `homes` property), do you want to omit the parent of that instead?

Comment: did you try to use settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

Comment: I have DTOs which may have a nested property at any depth level that is a Dictionary. I want to remove that Dictionary property based on some criteria and if some of the parent properties result to be empty after that operation I would like to remove them too.

Comment: I tried with settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, but I don't want to ignore all default values.

Comment: So how do you define the properties that you want to exclude?

Comment: [Try it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36884902/how-to-omit-ignore-skip-empty-object-literals-in-the-produced-json)

Answer (score 0):

`instance`is already the specified type. You can simply cast:

```
instance =>
                {
                    var value = (IDictionary)instance;
                    return value != null && value.Keys.Count() > 0
                };
```

Try if that works. If not, check with debug what the contents of `value` are and post back.

EDIT: I see this is about a nested property. Please provide the code of the inherited classes.