# Using JSON.Net how can I serialize a dynamic and force all string values to lower case?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, azure-cosmosdb

In an object I am serializing to a document database I have a dynamic property that needs all string values written in lower-case for indexing purposes. I tried using a custom converter for this, but that requires me to write serialization code for several different types. All I want is the standard serialization behavior, but with the string values forced to lower-case. Given the flexibility of the Newtonsoft library this seems like it should be straightforward, I just haven't found the right interface.

Note that I don't have direct control over serialization. I am writing to Azure COSMOSDB, and their client library uses JSON.Net for serialization. I am able to pass in a custom serializer to use.

**Update**

The following appears to work. Steps are:

1. add code to populate the dynamic property via JToken.FromObject()
2. use code below to force all string values to lower-case (arrays were tricky)
3. send object to CosmosDB

   ```
   private static JToken JTokenStringValuesToLower(JToken startToken)
   {
       Stack<JEnumerable<JToken>> tokenStack = new Stack<JEnumerable<JToken>>();
       tokenStack.Push(startToken.Children());

       while (tokenStack.Count != 0)
       {
           JEnumerable<JToken> children = tokenStack.Pop();

           foreach (JToken child in children)
           {
               if (child.Type == JTokenType.Property)
               {
                   JProperty property = (JProperty)child;

                   if (child.HasValues)
                   {
                       tokenStack.Push(child.Children());
                   }

                   if (property.Value.Type == JTokenType.String)
                   {
                       property.Value = property.Value.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();
                   }
               }
               else if (child.Type == JTokenType.Array && child.HasValues)
               {
                   JArray array = (JArray)child;
                   JToken[] arrayItems = new JToken[array.Count];
                   int idx = 0;
                   bool modified = false;

                   foreach (JToken arrayItem in array.Children())
                   {
                       arrayItems[idx++] = arrayItem;
                   }

                   for (int i = 0; i < arrayItems.Length; ++i)
                   {
                       JToken token = arrayItems[i];

                       if (token.Type == JTokenType.String)
                       {
                           modified = true;
                           arrayItems[i] = token.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();
                       }
                   }

                   if (modified)
                   {
                       array.Clear();

                       foreach (JToken item in arrayItems)
                       {
                           array.Add(item);
                       }
                   }
               }
               else if (child.HasValues)
               {
                   tokenStack.Push(child.Children());
               }
           }
       }

       return startToken;
   }
   ```

Comment: Do you mean, field names or field values?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789593/force-lowercase-property-names-from-json-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Values. I edited the question.

Comment: Since it's the values that you want forced to lowercase I don't think this is a job for JSON.net or any Json serialiser. Can't you simply pass all of the values through a conversion function before saving to CosmosDB?  Or if you know they're all strings can't you just say someDynamicObject.someProperty.ToString().ToLower() on each of the fields?

Answer (score 0):

For a similar question, I found the use of `JToken` very powerful, as [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36902293/21336) (SO) shows how to iterate through a JSON data structure and manipulate each data node based on type or content.

Comment: I think this would work if I had control over serialization. I edited my question to note that I am using Azure CosmosDB, and their client library handles serialization. I can pass in a serializer, but not the serialized string.